# prestashop v 1.5.6.2 server/domain migration

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system, prestashop, server-migration

I've a problem with migration my prestashop system from old server & domain to new.

I've copied the full folder tree from old server and have done dump of DB, then pasted that to the new server and import DB to the new one. After that my problem occurs,  after complete those steps, when i call new url, system automatically redirect me to the old domain.
So i've changed in DB inside the table **`jr_shop_url`**, parameters **`domain`** and  **`domain_ssl`** to new ones, it returns me message: "**my.domain.com** is currently unable to handle this request".

Because of that problem i can't access admin panel either.

Any ideas what else i can do to make it works correctly or what have i done wrong ? :)

**P.S. I'm using PrestaShop version 1.5.6.2**

Comment: Did you follow the guide: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_configure_prestashop_to_work_with_another_domain/

Comment: `Log into cPanel and access phpMyAdmin.` --> Made changes in Phpmyadmin, without accessing _cPanel_, because it doesn't works for me.

Comment: Try the htaccess file, see what is in and correct it,

Comment: I've checked full .htaccess file and already correct all errors, by that i mean all places where was mentioned old domain, and put there new one. after that called `service apache2 restart`, and still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved, it was problem with permissions and folder owner, after changing folder's owner by `CHOWN -R user folder_path` and setting permissions to 775 it is working now.